# Good ways to navigate and retrieve a value in a table by string path in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

Was wondering for a good way to retrieve a value from a table by using a path, like some sort of scope.

As example for a path, `"SomePermissions/scope1/B"`, which gets the permissions from a table that looks like this

```lua
{
    ["SomePermissions"] = {
        ["scope1"] = {
            ["A"] = "special",
            ["B"] = true,
            ["C"] = false,
        }
    }
}
```

**What is a good way to do it?**

Here is the solution that I made for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013693/11161500

There could be small improvements for it, like giving the function the possibility to specify what to split for. Or when "SomePermissions/scope1/" has that "/" since it splits it, there would be an empty string value.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came up with, except string_split and string_totable:

```lua
function string_totable( str )
    local tbl = {}

    for i = 1, string.len( str ) do
        tbl[i] = string.sub( str, i, i )
    end

    return tbl
end

function string_split(str, separator, withpattern)
    if ( separator == "" ) then return string_totable( str ) end
    if ( withpattern == nil ) then withpattern = false end

    local ret = {}
    local current_pos = 1

    for i = 1, string.len( str ) do
        local start_pos, end_pos = string.find( str, separator, current_pos, not withpattern )
        if ( not start_pos ) then break end
        ret[ i ] = string.sub( str, current_pos, start_pos - 1 )
        current_pos = end_pos + 1
    end

    ret[ #ret + 1 ] = string.sub( str, current_pos )

    return ret
end


function GetTableValueByScope(tbl, path)
    local pathParts = string_split(path, "/")
    local enteredPaths = ""

    local curLocation = tbl
    for i=1,#pathParts do
        if (curLocation[pathParts[i]] == nil) then
            print("Entry \""..pathParts[i].."\" in \""..enteredPaths.."\", does not exist.")
            return nil
        end

        if (i == #pathParts) then -- If last value in pathParts
            return curLocation[pathParts[i]]
        else
            curLocation = curLocation[pathParts[i]]
            enteredPaths = enteredPaths..pathParts[i].."/"
        end
    end

    return curLocation
end


local exampleTable = {
    ["SomePermissions"] = {
        ["scope1"] = {
            ["A"] = "special",
            ["B"] = true,
            ["C"] = false,
        }
    }
}

print(GetTableValueByScope(exampleTable, "SomePermissions/scope1/B"))
-- Prints the value from "B".

print(GetTableValueByScope(exampleTable, "SomePermissions/scope1/ABC"))
-- Prints 'Entry "ABC" in "SomePermissions/scope1/", does not exist.'

local result = GetTableValueByScope(exampleTable, "SomePermissions/scope1")
-- "result" would now be "scope1" table.

-- The function returns a table, like that I can specifiy one scope and return the results within of what it found, and then call the function again with the next scope.

result = GetTableValueByScope(result, "B")
print(result)
-- Prints the value from "B".
```

Comment: This requires a `string.split` function which Lua does not provide.